# Как правильно сделать Linq запрос с ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Есть пару запросов:

```
string image = product.ProductCharacteristics
           .Where(c => c.Characteristic.Name == "Image")
           .Select(c => c.Characteristic.Value)
           .FirstOrDefault();

string price = product.ProductCharacteristics
           .Where(c => c.Characteristic.Name == "Price")
           .Select(c => c.Characteristic.Value)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Хочу сделать это одним запросом через словарь:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> dict = p.ProductCharacteristics
.ToDictionary(c=> c.Characteristic.Name, c=> c.Characteristic.Value)
```

но ничего не выходит, получаю ошибку. И вот так пробовал:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> dict = = product.ProductCharacteristics
                .Select(с => new { с.Characteristic.Name, с.Characteristic.Value })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .ToDictionary(с => с.Name, с => с.Value)
```

Тоже ошибка:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
ToDictionary[<>f__AnonymousType3`2,String,String]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2
System.String,System.String]], System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType3`2
System.String,System.String],System.String], System.Func`2
<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.String,System.String],System.String])' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Как правильно построить запрос?

Comment: А какую именно ошибку вы получаете? Обычно в ошибке говорится, что вы неправильно делаете.

Comment: У вас текст ошибки съел парсер. Может, положите его лучше в ответ как код?

Comment: добавил под кодом

Comment: Хм, а какая ошибка для _второго_ метода?

Comment: @VladD, а во втором методе where не используется:)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да, не используется. А что отсюда следует?

Comment: @VladD, вообще когда писал - лучше получалось :):):) по идее во втором методе просто всех должен был вернуть без ошибок

Comment: @VladD, поправил :)

Comment: @Grundy: Угу, второй метод выглядит правильно. Так что хотелось бы посмотреть на ошибку, которая получается при этом. Разве что дубликаты ключей?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это

```
dict = (product.ProductCharacteristics
              .AsNoTracking()
              .Where(x => x.Characteristic.Name == "Image")
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value))
              .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

Comment: в чем смысл второго вызова `ToDictionary`?